# jQuery Script Loading Queue

Tags: jquery, scripting, loading, external

So this question is an offshoot from another I recently asked, and this is more of a curiosity.

My other question dealt with dynamically loading in external js libraries. In my example, I had jQuery Template importing, followed by Knockout.js, both using .getScript(). When each finished loading, I was firing an alert, just to make sure they were loading correctly.

Here's the approximate code I was using (seems to work 'in order' on jsFiddle, so it could've been my code before. The question still stands though.):

```
$.getScript("https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js", function(){ alert('tmpl finished loading!'); });
$.getScript("http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js", function(){ alert('Knockout finished loading!'); });
```

I discovered that the alert for Knockout was firing before the tmpl library when I loaded up the page, even though it is listed second.

My assumption was that they would load synchronously, in queue fashion, waiting for the previous one to finish before loading the next. It appears that this is not the case.

**So I'm asking for verification of this assumption, and some explanation as to why this is/isn't the case. I'd also like to know if there is another [better] method to queue up script loading so that I don't run into problems with things being undefined because of dependencies on un-loaded scripts.**

Comment: Remember javascript just keeps going regardless of if the previous function is complete or not. In fact that's the definition of loading asynchronously. You were actually thinking they would load synchronously.

Comment: Woops, you're right. I did mean synchronously.

Comment: By the way, `ping raw.github.com :: ~110ms`, `ping cloud.github.com :: ~22ms` this is why the 2nd script was loaded first not something in your code in particular other than the problem outlined in the accepted answer. And be thankful for encountering it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test clearly contradicted your assumption. There's no queue, they each run concurrently. Which one completes first depends on file sizes, network timing, etc.

If you want to ensure that one loads after the other, put the call to load the second library in the first library's callback function:

```
$.getScript("https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js", function(){
    alert('tmpl finished loading!');
    $.getScript("http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js", function(){ 
        alert('Knockout finished loading!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing that in my full code, something was causing the tmpl library to load slower. Not sure what. Is this method of nesting loads fairly common?

Comment: Maybe because you're using SSL for it?

Comment: Just edited my first comment with a question relating to your answer.

Comment: I don't know how common dynamic loading of JS is in the first place, but maybe you should look at RequireJS if your needs are complex.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think you've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could but all your libraries in a single js file in the order you would want to load them. This reduces the number of requests that need to be made as an added bonus!